# Cycles render stops halfway through render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render an object using Cycles render. My object is simple but it won't finish rendering this object. I downloaded a couple of shared models, much more complex, and they render fine. I've left my object rendering for 15 minutes and it won't finish. Blender render will work, as does the OpenGL option.

I'm using a Macbook pro, 2.2ghz i7, 4gb ram. I'm also using Blender 2.7. The attached image is how far it will get. What am I doing wrong?

[render example http://www.guitarsean.info/Blender_render.jpg](http://www.guitarsean.info/Blender_render.jpg)

Comment: Just as a test, I created a brand new file, new object. Same problem with render, downloaded models still render fine. (and thanks for the title edit Garrett)

Comment: I think you should file a bug report including your system specs at https://developer.blender.org/ and also be sure to send them a .blend file using the upload system at PasteAll http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Before ever reporting a bug, download the latest build from builder.blender.org and test it in there. I have a feeling this was one of the bugs in 2.70 and thus warranted the 2.70a release, but try it in a buildbot build anyway.

Comment: Also check that you haven't got the samples up too high, it may just be calculating without visible change. Do you see any cpu usage while it's rendering?

Comment: The sampling seems to be the culprit. I had it set to 100. CPU usage spiked to 760% (which seems impossible) and the cooling fans go crazy. I dropped sampling to 10 and it's running smoothly. At this point I don't really understand sampling in Blender. The video tutorial I watched recommended setting it to 100, but he was also using GPU processing on an Nvidia card. My laptop probably just can't handle that. Thanks for the tip sampler!